# Text search too slow for large array with search Bar & tableview on iPhone

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift2

I have a large array of size around 100000 entries. I am displaying it when user search in UISearchBar and it display filtered data on tableview. However the search bar is too slow while doing dynamic search. i.e I am filtering the table everytime the user puts in a character on search bar. As a result it gives entered text on searchBar as very late response. I just need to wait for it to appear on searchBar.

This is what I am trying to filter my array.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text

        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: [NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch ,
        NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch])
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: One possible solution is to start a timer (say 2 seconds) in `textDidChange`. Each time `textDidChange` is called you restart the timer. When the timer expires you filter the table. This means that you don't update the table while they are still typing but you do when they stop

Comment: Is there any different way to make it fast without any timer.

Comment: Free text searching through 100,000 records is going to be slow unless you can throw more CPU at it; which you can't;  Can you query against a database rather than an array?

Comment: Yes, even I have tried with FMDB SQLite database which consist of 80000 records. Due to this I thought let's try with array but both are giving me same response.

Comment: Yes, the only way you can really make it any faster is if you can do a prefix search rather than a substring search, so words starting with "cat" rather than words containing "cat"

Comment: Ok Thanx. I'll try words starting with "cat" rather than words containing "cat"

Comment: If you can do that then an indexed database will perform better.  You can also try sorting your array and use a binary search or even hash buckets with an array for each first letter.

Comment: Ok, actually I'm just testing with array, but for my app I need database and to resolve this issues I'm trying in different way. Finally my intention is to get fast response through app for large database.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are not blocking the main_queue. Maybe you are calling sqlite functions from main queue. If so, try using FMDatabaseQueue and call the methods from background queue and update the tableview from main queue. This will handle everything for you.

Comment: First I'm using FMDB SQLite database with 80000 entries. Right now I'm just testing simple string array of size 100000 entries.  And I am searching it using searchBar and displaying on tableview. Then also it gives very slow response when I start searching using my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try query with Realm.io?

I Knew that faster than any DB manager in iOS now.

[Realm.io](https://realm.io)

Comment: No I haven't try query with Realm.io